# How should I write tests for my Forms in Django?

Tags: python, django

Have anyone idea how should I write unit test for this form :

```
class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(
                            choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES,
                            coerce=int)
    update = forms.BooleanField(required=False,
                            initial=False,
                            widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

Comment: This seems more like a code review or software engineering SE question

Comment: Definitely not Code Review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.forms import CartAddProductForm

class MyTests(TestCase):

    def test_form(self):
        form_data = {'quantity':100, 'update':True}
        form = CartAddProductForm(data=form_data)
        self.AssertTrue(form.is_valid())

    def test_form_without_update(self):
        form_data = {'quantity':100}
        form = CartAddProductForm(data=form_data)
        self.AssertTrue(form.is_valid())

    def test_form_is_invalid(self):
        form_data = {'quantity':'foo', 'update':'bar'}
        form = CartAddProductForm(data=form_data)
        self.AssertFalse(form.is_valid())
```

There are so many test methods, you can test in a form , it depend descriptive test you are trying to test .

I found this good article on test cases : http://test-driven-django-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/05-forms.html